# Laravel Websockets Reverse Proxy SSL

Tags: laravel, apache, reverse-proxy, proxypass, laravel-websockets

I decided to use the Laravel Websockets in my projects, which downloading and testing the package locally does the work, but when I tried to deploy my Laravel Websocket application to the remote server (AWS EC2) for Production purpose the websocket dashboard won't connect and says  Channels current state is unavailable  I also get pusher error in the console :

WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com:6001/app/11236shfDs6pFJ5udC5P23a?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.4.0&flash=false' failed:

I have been researching the web and online forums to find a solution and debug this issue but unfortunately, I wasn't successful.

I double checked my configuration files, ssl certificates, env and .......

Please help me out with this issue to troubleshoot the problem.

I tried to setup Reverse Proxy for it but I'm not familiar with these configs and I'm not sure if I set it right :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.net
    ServerName socket.mydomain.net
    ServerAlias socket.mydomain.net
    ServerAlias www.socket.mydomain.net

    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/ws/(.*)       wss://127.0.0.1:6001/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:6001/

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/websocket/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html/websocket">
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.mydomain.net/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.mydomain.net/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: were you successful in solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are no configuration files and it's even unclear which web-server it is.

You cannot run WSS protocol on port `6001`, externally that's always port `443`.
When WS should be running on `6001`, you'd have to setup reverse proxy for it.

It can be used as [Pusher Replacement](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/pusher), since it also [depends on](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/blob/master/composer.json#L31) Ratchet.
When struggling with the reverse proxy, Pusher may be easier to set up.
This would at least be an [example for ngnix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64544755/549372), to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: I serve it using apache and been trying to setup reverse proxy for it but haven't been successful.